# Date in JSON Object with Mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I am fetching results of mysql  and i have datetime field in mysql and when i fetch result

it is showing

**Mon Sep 15 2014 11:59:55 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) )**

Sql querty become

```
SELECT * from table where created_at >=Mon Sep 15 2014 11:59:55 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) )
```

But in MYSQL i have **2014-09-15 12:40:37**

I want to compare two dates.

Any body have idea how to compare.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
to convert the string to a real date

```
mysql> select str_to_date('Mon Sep 15 2014 11:59:55 GMT+0530','%a %b %d %Y %H:%i:%s') as date;
+---------------------+
| date                |
+---------------------+
| 2014-09-15 11:59:55 |
+---------------------+
```

So in the query you can use as

```
SELECT * from table 
where created_at >= str_to_date('Mon Sep 15 2014 11:59:55 GMT+0530','%a %b %d %Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Comment: SELECT STR_TO_DATE(`created_at`,'%a %b %d %Y %H:%i:%s') as currr_date FROM `following_follower_categories` WHERE 1 /. it is showing null

Comment: you said in mysql your data is saved as `2014-09-15 12:40:37` ?

Comment: yes, it is , but when i fetched data from mysql having json output, it is showing 11:59:55 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: i think you need to check json encoding part, which is the conversion.